# Duplicate values on column A to column B - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I'm trying to achieve the following result:

[image]

So if column A has duplicate values, I want to show these duplicate values on column B. Here is what I have tried so far. But the code just makes Apple to show two times in a column B. How would I need to alter my code to make it work the way I want?

```js
function findDuplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow).getValues()

  var dataUnique = data.reduce(function (out, item) {
  return out.concat(out.filter(function (comp) {
    return item.toString() != comp.toString();
  }).length ? [] : [item])
  }, []);

  var newValues = sheet.getRange(1,2,dataUnique.length).setValues(dataUnique)
}
```

This is the result when I run the code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17WyKhkr0qR8bMb0wFxjRhc32YHWFz8eMCEz3i4Q1i7c/edit#gid=2100307022) created specifically to address this question. It contains the following code that will take values from A and output the result in column B:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var input = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues().filter(e=>e[0]).map(e=>e[0]);
  var inputLower = input.map(e=>e.toLowerCase());

  var output = new Array();
  input.forEach(function (e,i,arr){if(inputLower.indexOf(e.toLowerCase())!=i && output.indexOf(e)==-1){output.push(e)}});
  sheet.getRange(1,2,output.length,1).setValues(output.map(e=>[e]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for good suggestion, but I need to solve this using Apps Script

Comment: @Tane I've updated my answer from the formula  -- UNIQUE(FILTER( ... -- To an Apps Script solution as you asked for.

Comment: Amazing! Works like a charm. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity, would it be possible to make this solution case sensitive, so values like "value" and "Value" would be considered duplicate? Just asking, as I might need that in the future :)

Comment: Adding this solves the problem:
  // Convert all letters to lowercase
  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(/á|à|ã|ä|A/gi, 'a');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().toLowerCase();
   }
  }
  range.setValues(data);

Comment: @Tane woah. that's crazy looking.  I was gonna  say i made a small tweak to the code that handles the case question.  I've amended the code above in the answer it uses the .toLowerCase() function.  Give it a try if you like.

Comment: Yeah your solution is way better, thanks, works great!